# assertion failed error with Emberjs v0.9.7.1 - You cannot provide a template block if you also specified a templateName

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

After including latest emberjs 0.9.7.1 js, I get the error below.

Please, Any help on what below error means?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You cannot provide a template block if you also specified a templateName
```

Answer (score 10):

The error seems clear. You cannot set a template block and a template name in the same time. I suppose you have defined something like:

```
App.MyEmberView = Ember.View.create({

template : Ember.Handlebars.compile('...template string..'),
templateName: 'MyTemplateName'

});
```