# Emberjs - You cannot provide a template block if you also specified a templateName

Tags: ember.js

I am working on the [Ember Auth Rails Demo](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/wiki) and after the Model UI chapter am getting this error:

```
You cannot provide a template block if you also specified a templateName
```

I don't know where this is coming from and do not see anywhere that I am specifying both a template block and a templateName (as indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276603/assertion-failed-error-with-emberjs-v0-9-7-1-you-cannot-provide-a-template-blo)).  Any idea on where this might be arising?  I was thinking perhaps somewhere in the views directory, perhaps in auth.js.coffee, which looks like this:

```
Planbug.AuthView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'auth'
```

Or perhaps in views/auth/sign-in.js.coffee, which looks like this:

```
Planbug.AuthSignInView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'auth/sign-in'

  email: null
  password: null

  submit: (event, view) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    Planbug.Auth.signIn
      data:
        email:    @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
```

I am trying to follow the demo closely but I might have a typo somewhere or maybe am doing something slightly different.  Any idea on where to look for conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling either of these views using the handlebars `view` helper.

This error would be thrown if you call the block version of view

```
{{#view Planbug.AuthView}}
  Something 
{{/view}}`
```

instead of the non-block version

```
{{view Planbug.AuthView}}
```